# Excel Conditional Formatting, Referencing 2 cells to the Right with conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-formatting

I have a list of students who are between the ages of 3 and 5. lets say column A has the code, Column D has the childs age & Column F has their age group (3-5) If their age exceeds the age group then the Cell in column A will highlight Red. I am just not sure how to write this code correctly, all of the combinations i have tried come up with an error or just don't do anything.

IF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,7)="3-5" & (OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,4)>5 *{THEN FILL CELL RED}* *{ELSE NO FILL}*

Comment: Please tell us what have you searched till yet.

Comment: you can see I have searched how to reference a cell without changing the location of the reference if the cell is moved to another location. I just don't know how to write the IF statement correctly. I have a list of students who are between the ages of 3 and 5. lets say column A has the code, Column D has the childs age & Column F has their age group (3-5) If their age exceeds the age group then the Cell in column A will highlight Red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first part of the statement you are checking whether the cell 7 columns across = "3-5". You don't need to use offset for this, you can just reference the cell 7 across directly.

So if you're applying the conditional formatting to A1 that part of the formula would just be =IF(H1="3-5",{then},{else}).

If you just want TRUE or FALSE as the answer you don't need the IF statement, so this shortens to: =H1="3-5",

If you're applying the conditional formatting to a range instead of just an individual cell, say A1:B10, then you write the formula for the cell in the top left of the that range. So for A1:B10 you would still you the same formulae as above.

For the second part of the statement, using the same logic as above, you get: =E1>5

To check both statements together you need to wrap them in the =AND() function, giving you this as the final formula for your conditional formatting:

```
=AND(H1="3-5",E1>5)
```

Comment: Your description of simplified ways of achieving a similar result allowed me to figure out how to write the code the way I needed it. =AND(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,7)="3-5yo",OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,4)>5)

Answer (score 0):

By using the AND function I can achieve the desired result without cell references moving if a cell is relocated.

```
=AND(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,7)="3-5yo",OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,4)>5)
```